# Growing partitions in opposite directions?

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I have this idea for a partitioning scheme that would be quite useful for me. It seems very obvious(?), so I feel it's not done due to hardware-level details and long-ingrained characteristics of file systems.

[image]

It's quite simple: we would have partitions on opposite sides of the disk that can grow in opposite directions. This would allow us to grow them independently without the need to move partitions.

My question is: if this is not feasible, why exactly?

I understand that HDDs should not be read in arbitrary ways due to the limitations of head movement (I estimate reading blocks/pages from right to left would take ~2x head movement time). SSDs also have different read/write speeds for random vs sequential access, but I can't see how reading entire pages/blocks in arbitrary positions would be a problem. If this is right, this scheme should have been feasible on SSDs.

OS kernels, in theory, should be able to translate the address space of an "inverted" partition so they can be used at the file system/software level transparently.

I know that volume managers and such solve this problem, so there's not a big demand for this kind of solution, but I am particularly curious about hypothetical solutions that would be OS-independent. (why no hardware volume managers :v)

Comment: Apple's APFS has no hard boundaries for a volume, they're entirely flexible. For Windows, I guess you'll have to wait for MS to re-write NTFS. I doubt any future file system will even care about how HDs work.

Comment: While not exactly your scheme that you describe IBM mainframe can be configured to use a similar scheme.

Comment: The difficulty would be at the filesystem level - the filesystem would need to be rewritten to work from the end backwards - added complexity where you least want it.  You can partially/significantly solve this problem by abstracting the filesystem away from the partition with a lot of other advantages as well - LVM for Linux does just that.

Comment: @davidgo I'm pretty sure this could be done before FS level. The kernel would have to just map the block/pages address space reversed and it would work transparently for the FS itself.

Comment: @davidgo But yeah, I know this would not be feasible in practice. Its more of a thought experiment, and it seems very feasible to do in practice, let's say, if GPT partitioning did add a "reversed" flag for partitions.

Comment: I know LVM solves this exact problem, and Windows has also it's own solution; but they don't work with both OSes simultaneously. The use case for this would be exactly for using with _multiple_ OSes when we can't antecipate the future demand of space for each partition.

Comment: In the early days of Windows, Norton Utilities used to defragment your disk in this sort of fashion (as an option).  As an example, you could arrange your readonly files, often-used files, often-modified files etc. in layers.